# Apache Zeppelin installation grunt build error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

My configuration is as follows:

```
Ubuntu 15.04
Java 1.7
Spark 1.4.1
Hadoop 2.7
Maven 3.3.3
```

I am trying to install Apache Zeppelin after successfully cloning it from github and using the following command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Despite several attempts, I am getting the following error after some initial success:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:grunt (grunt build)
>   on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'grunt --no-color'
>   failed. (error code 3) -> [Help 1]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Regards,

Naveen Xavier

Answer (score 4):

It fails because of a karma:test fails on PhantomJS. Remove the karma test from Gruntfile.js inside zeppelin-web folder. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a pre-built version available if you search for it. I'm using that because of build problems

link: https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

first install npm

```
sudo apt-get install npm
then go inside zeppelin-0.6.2/zeppelin-web
sudo npm install
```

then run

```
mvn -U clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-2.0 -Phadoop-2.7 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pscala-2.10 -Dmaven.repo.local=/media/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I still got this error when I tried to install Zeppelin on Windows, it might save some time for someone.

A bug has been opened for this on Jira, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1239 and the solution there helped to solve the problem.

In `\zeppelin-web\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-util\index.js`, line 182, change the following

```
//args = opts.args || [];
cmd = process.execPath;
args = [].concat(opts.cmd, opts.args);
```