# Apache Zeppelin: Trying to build from from source code but zeppelin-web fails

Tags: eclipse, apache-zeppelin, maven-eclipse-plugin

I cloned the 'master' copy of Apache Zeppelin from https://github.com/apache/zeppelin in my Eclipse workspace and followed the steps for installation given as follows:

> - Created a new Java project and imported zeppelin.
> - Converted it into a Maven project
> - I had previously installed NodeJS and subsequently bower.
> - Activate Maven repository index updates
> - Window=>Preferences=>Maven and checked the following:
>
>   - Download Artifact Sources
>   - Download Artifact JavaDoc
>   - Download repository index updates on startup
>   - Update Maven projects on startup
> - Made sure I had JDK installed
>
>   - C:/Program Files (or X86)/Java/.. should have JDK(NOT JRE)
> - Windows => Preferences => search for ‘jre’
>
>   - Installed JREs => Add… => Standard VM
>   - JRE home: Installed jdk folder location/jdk1.8.***
> - Right-click on the Project=>Run As => Run Configurations
>
>   - Double click Maven Build
>
>     - Name: clean package
>     - Base directory: the zeppelin directory
>     - Goals: clean package
>     - Check ‘Skip Tests’
>     - JRE tab=> choose JDK(installed above) instead of JRE
>     - Run

Most modules pass except zeppelin-web onward

> [INFO] Reactor Summary:
>   
> [INFO] 
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [ 20.674 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [01:55 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [02:36 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Display system apis ...................... SUCCESS [01:21 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [03:32 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [04:05 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  6.287 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  3.118 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  3.650 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Livy interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [ 30.402 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: HBase interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [04:02 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Pig Interpreter ................... SUCCESS [03:37 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [ 16.102 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: JDBC interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [ 17.661 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: File System Interpreters ................. SUCCESS [ 16.002 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SUCCESS [04:32 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SUCCESS [02:22 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  5.049 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Python interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [  4.519 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [02:00 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Cassandra interpreter ............. SUCCESS [03:49 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SUCCESS [01:47 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: BigQuery interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [ 24.181 s]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Alluxio interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [02:17 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [01:27 min]
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
>   
> [INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [INFO] Total time: 41:58 min
>   
> [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-20T10:47:21-05:00
>   
> [INFO] Final Memory: 141M/508M
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:grunt (grunt build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'grunt build --no-color' failed. (error code 3) -> [Help 1]
>   
> [ERROR] 
>   
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   
> [ERROR] 
>   
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>   
> [ERROR] 
>   
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>   
> [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :zeppelin-web

When I did a -e and -X for a debug and error stack I got this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:grunt (grunt build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'grunt build --no-color' failed. (error code 3) -> [Help 1]
>   
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.25:grunt (grunt build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>   
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
>   
>     at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:66)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>   
>     ... 20 more
>   
> Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'grunt build --no-color' failed. (error code 3)
>   
>     at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:59)
>   
>     at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.GruntMojo.execute(GruntMojo.java:64)
>   
>     at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:64)
>   
>     ... 22 more
>   
> [ERROR]

I have been looking through SO for weeks but this is the closest post I found: [Apache Zeppelin installation grunt build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352309/apache-zeppelin-installation-grunt-build-error) and even asked the person if a solution was found, no response. The solution posted in there didn't work for me.

I am doing all this on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard box. I'd be deeply grateful if someone could point me in the right direction in terms of a solution.

Comment: have you try to build on tag v0.6.2?

Comment: v0.6.2? Isn't the latest zeppelin version  v0.6.

Comment: 0.6.2 released on Oct 15, 2016

Comment: Yes,you are right! However, I had pulled the latest version yesterday morning before running it and I see the same error!

Comment: latest means change fast. I would ONLY to use it if I want to contribute PR or must use some feature there.

Comment: I downloaded and tried to build tag v0.6.2 and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the frontend webapp build fails on your windows box.

Please try running `npm run build` manually on the latest sources - that will give more verbose logs and will help to find the reason.

At least on Linux - there are [few pre-requests](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/install/build.html#build-requirements) in order for it to work i.e `libfontconfig`

Comment: Yes. I did not install libfontconfig. But I couldn't figure out how to do it in Windows. I think my problem could be from the absence of 'libfontconfig'. Google-ing it does not give me any credible information.